# Multipeer Connectivity - number of devices that can be connected to a service?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bonjour, multipeer-connectivity

I was learning about Multipeer Connectivity framework of iOS from the tutorial site http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/ .

The example provided was really useful to understand the concept, in which, the devices simply have a view and its color can be changed by near devices.

My Question is that **is there is any limitation to the number of devices(iPhone) that can be connected to the available service at a time? if it is over bluetooth?** please let know, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, It has a limitation to max 7 peers. That means 8 devices you can connect. But you may have multiple instance of multi-peer session.

Multi-peer connectivity transfer data via Wifi/Bluetooth with the best option automatically choice. If one of the two options is missing then other option will be chosen to transfer data.

You can see this
http://www.slideshare.net/waynehartman/multipeer-connectivity

which claims:

18. Limitations • Limit to 8 connected peers. • Data transfer is slow—especially on Bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks, @jamil65able , any links to refer about the connectivity limitations? please add

Comment: if you connect 1 devices to multipeer default feature of multipeer browser will show you remain 6 devices to connect